# Why does my Edge CSS animation become out of sync?

Tags: html, css, animation, microsoft-edge

Can anyone please explain how my below code can possibly get out of sync in Microsoft Edge. If you watch a few loops (10sec) the fade and the move animation are out of sync and it does not look correct. It should fade away and then reset the boxes behind the center one before revealing. Each loop makes it further and further out of sync.

```css
.rhu_bswn_packages {
    position:relative
}

.rhu_bswn_red_package {
    position:absolute;
    width: 33%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 7%;
}
.rhu_bswn_blue_package {
    position:absolute;
    width: 39%;
    left: 32%;
    z-index: 3;
}
.rhu_bswn_gold_package {
    position:absolute;
    width: 33%;
    left: 60%;
    top: 12%;
}

.rhu_bswn_red_package {
    -webkit-animation:rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_red 10s infinite;
            animation:rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_red 10s infinite;
    opacity:0.01;
    left:34%
}

@-webkit-keyframes rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_red {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(0.01) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:0; }
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:1; }
    20% { left:10%; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    80% { left:10%; -webkit-transform:scale(1); transform:scale(1); opacity:1; }
    99% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); left:10%; }
    100% { left:34%; opacity:0; }
}

@keyframes rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_red {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(0) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:0; }
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:1; }
    20% { left:10%; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    80% { left:10%; -webkit-transform:scale(1); transform:scale(1); opacity:1; }
    99% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); left:10%; }
    100% { left:34%; opacity:0; }
}

.rhu_bswn_gold_package {
    -webkit-animation:rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_gold 10s infinite;
            animation:rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_gold 10s infinite;
    opacity:0;
    left:34%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_gold {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(0) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:0; }
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:1; }
    20% { left:60%; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    80% { left:60%; opacity:1; }
    99% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); left:60%; }
    100% { left:34%; opacity:0; }
}

@keyframes rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_gold {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(0) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:0; }
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(6deg); left:34%; opacity:1; }
    20% { left:60%; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    80% { left:60%; opacity:1; }
    99% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); left:60%; }
    100% { left:34%; opacity:0; }
}

.rhu_bswn_blue_package {
    -webkit-animation:rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_blue 10s infinite;
            animation:rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_blue 10s infinite;
    opacity:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_blue {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(9deg); transform:scale(0) rotate(9deg); opacity:1; }
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(9deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(9deg); opacity:1; }
    20% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform:scale(1); transform:scale(1); opacity:1; }
    99% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes rhu_fade_and_rotate_reveal_blue {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(0) rotate(9deg); transform:scale(0) rotate(9deg); opacity:1; }
    10% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(9deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(9deg); opacity:1; }
    20% { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
    80% { -webkit-transform:scale(1); transform:scale(1); opacity:1; }
    99% { opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="rhu_bswn_packages">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRGdxdUWpcUYiwE4ezU0rpIyRC_YdT356UVnoEAa5D3SQkFhIbo" class="rhu_bswn_red_package" />
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTjiEbXaySZqDjpnx4M0ClnOcsrVrDHattx-K2n4ufxEEUR1PB5" class="rhu_bswn_blue_package" />
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQpcuQfLixcr0KV10mHN34i2Hxe2mU5q1VyTOmN9Ju3js-nx17R" class="rhu_bswn_gold_package" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML. Also note that you probably do not need the webkit prefixes since browsers have been OK with those for many years.

Comment: I reproduced the issue and I think it might be a issue with Edge. I'm confirming this with other senior engineers and I'll inform you if I have any updates. Thanks for your understanding.